# Encryption/decryption using AesManaged ECB or CBC dost not work with .bin file

Tags: c#, encryption

I found this code and used it in VS 2017 C# to encrypt and decrypt a file. If I encrypt a .txt file, then decrypt the file and compare the decrypted output to the original file, then it matches. If I try with a .bin file, it does not match and I can't figure out why. I would think it should work with any kind of file?
Can anybody see what the problem is?

```
static void AESEncryptCBC(string plainText, Stream encryptedOutput, byte[] key)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText == string.Empty)
            return;

        if (key == null | key.Length == 0)
            return;

        if (encryptedOutput == null)
            return;



        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Key = key;


            var salt = new byte[16];

            using (var rngCSP = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rngCSP.GetBytes(salt);
            }
            aes.IV = salt;


            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                encryptedOutput.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);//write the salt to the begining of the stream


                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedOutput, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {
                        writer.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void AESEncryptECB(string plainText, Stream encryptedOutput, byte[] key)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText == string.Empty)
            return;

        if (key == null | key.Length == 0)
            return;

        if (encryptedOutput == null)
            return;



        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            var salt = new byte[16];

            using (var rngCSP = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rngCSP.GetBytes(salt);
            }
            aes.IV = salt;


            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                encryptedOutput.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length); //write the salt to the begining of the stream

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedOutput, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {
                        writer.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    static string AESDecryptECB(Stream encryptedInput, byte[] key)
    {
        if (encryptedInput == null || encryptedInput.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (key == null || key.Length == 0)
            return null;



        var salt = new byte[16];
        encryptedInput.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);


        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = salt;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;


            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedInput, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                    {
                        return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static string AESDecryptCBC(Stream encryptedInput, byte[] key)
    {
        if (encryptedInput == null || encryptedInput.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (key == null || key.Length == 0)
            return null;



        var salt = new byte[16];
        encryptedInput.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);


        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = salt;


            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedInput, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                    {
                        return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In short, your issue is caused by the fact that you can't represent arbitrary binary data as a string.

The `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` classes work with text.  Binary data is not text.  There is no concept of a character encoding.  You should be working with `byte[]`'s at this level, not strings!  Try to eliminate the `StreamWriter/Reader` from your code.

Comment: @ChristianB - That is _replacing_ the StreamReader/Writer. You don't need them, a Stream can deal with `byte[]` directly. Remove them.